# Logic behind a small piece of multithreading code in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, locking

I am currrently reading a book on multithreading program in Python and do not really understand the logic behind the following code, which illustrates that the threading lock can be acquired in one thread and released in another.

```
import threading
import time

shared = 0
lock = threading.Lock()

def funcA():
    global shared
    for i in range(10):
        time.sleep(1)
        shared += 10
        print(f"Thread A wrote: {shared}")
        lock.acquire()

def funcB():
    global shared
    lock.acquire()
    for i in range(10):
        time.sleep(1)
        shared -= 10
        print(f"Thread B wrote: {shared}")
        lock.release()

t1 = threading.Thread(target=funcA)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=funcB)
t1.start()
t2.start()
t1.join()
t2.join()
```

I have two main questions:

1. In **funcA**, the lock is acquired once for each *i* in range(10), but is never released as *i* moves from one index to another. How is this possible that there is no error raised?
2. Similar to Question 1, the lock is never released at all in **funcA**, how is it possible that **funcB** can acquire the lock again without any problem?

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Does this help from the docs? *"When the state is locked, `acquire()` blocks until a call to `release()` in another thread changes it to unlocked, then the `acquire()` call resets it to locked and returns."* https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#lock-objects

Comment: As a matter of _style,_ You should never unlock something called "lock" or "mutex" in a different thread from the one that locked it. Use something called "semaphore" for that instead. When other programmers see "lock" or "mutex," they expect that you are using it to guard variables that are shared between the threads, and when they see "semaphore," they will expect that you are using it to send a signal from one thread to another. Obeying this rule won't make your code work any better,\* but it will make other programmers happier to read your code and collaborate with you.

Comment: \* Except, in _some_ programming languages/libraries where you'll get a run-time error if one thread tries to unlock a `mutex` that was locked by a different thread.

Comment: If you put a call to `time.sleep(2)` at the start of `funcA` then `funcB` will raise an exception because it is trying to release a lock that is not locked. If you instead put the call to `time.sleep(2)` at the start of `funcB` then both threads will hang trying to acquire a lock that is already held (by `funcA`). So this code is full of race conditions and is a study in what you should not do. If the code terminates as is, it is due to "luck."